# Excel COUNTIF with optional parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[SessionDate], "<" & $B3, Table1[District], CHART!$J$1)
```

Cells in **B3**, **B4**, **B5**, etc. have a date value that I want to sum if the date value of the data row (`SessionDate`) is less than this value. Works fine.

Cell **J1** has a drop-down list of districts, which the user can choose from. Works fine.

However, if the user clears the drop-down, I'd like it to count data for ALL districts.

I can do this using something like:

`=IF(J1="", [without_district_filter], [with_district_filter])`

... but I need a couple of these filters, and would prefer not to have a bunch of messy nested `IF`s.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines `=COUNTIFS(Table1[SessionDate], "<" & $B3, Table1[District], "<>")` or `=COUNTIFS(Table1[SessionDate], "<" & $B3, Table1[District], "*")` will count all rows where `Table1[SessionDate]` < $B3 and `Table1[District]` is not blank.

You can use an `IF` statement within the `COUNTIFS` to check this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[SessionDate], "<" & $B3, Table1[District], IF(Len(CHART!$J$1)<1,"<>",CHART!$J$1))
```

This will not work if you have any rows where `Table1[District]` is empty

Answer (score -2):

Create a District called "ALL" that includes all of the rows and make the user select that to count all of the data.

Comment: `Table1[District]` can contain the District, or it can be "ALL", but 1 cell cannot contain 2 values at the same time.

Comment: Why can't the drop down list in cell J1 have a named ranged that includes all of the data?

Comment: It does.  Consider the following:  You have 3 columns, "District" and "People" and "Building".  You want to count how many buildings have less than 3 people, and you want a drop-down (containing all your Districts) to choose between which District to count Buildings in.  BUT, you *also* want to be able to select an option to count ALL Districts at once, using **the same drop-down**.